# Jquery to get value from dropdown

Tags: jquery

i have to get the id and value of a selected ones.

what i mean is in the following example.i only set n.id as option value.i have to set

```
<option value="' + n.id,n.names  + '">' like that


jobs.forEach(function (n) {
            html += '<option value="' + n.id  + '">' + n.names + '</option>';
            i++;
        });


  html += '<option value="' + n.id ,n.names  + '">' + n.names + '</option>';
```

the above code is not correct.how can i pass both id and value as comma separate and get that values separately

```
<tr>
                        <td width="200px">Jobs</td>
                        <td> 
                            <select id="jobSel" class="longcombo"></select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html += '<option value="' + n.id +","+n.names  + '">' + n.names + '</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use text() and val() like below:

```
html += '<option value="' + n.id + '"'>' + n.names + '</option>';
```

in jQuery, you can use,

```
$('#jobSel option:selected').val() to get value (n.id)
$('#jobSel option:selected').text() to get the display name (n.names)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above example gives you a way to access what is present in the selected visible value.

You may append the variables like

String myString = selMulti+","+yourIDValue

Hope this serves

HTML

```
<select multiple='multiple' id="selMulti">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>    
</select>
<input type="button" id="go" value="Go!" />
<div style="margin-top: 10px;" id="result"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    var selMulti = $("#selMulti option:selected").text();
    $("#result").text(selMulti);
});
```

JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2C523/12/